# dojo tooltip dialog box

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a grid. In grid column added dropdown Button and on click of button open tooltip dialog box But tooltipdialog box open for few second after that disappear.

I want when click on button it shows and on cancel button hide.Please suggest if any idea .
I am following [enter link description here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/TooltipDialog.html#dijit-tooltipdialog)

**1.dialog.jsp**

```
 <table id="eventDialogInstructorTextBox" dojotype="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" data-dojo-           props="selectionMode:'none'" style="height: 50px;width:100%;align:top;background:white;margin-left:2%">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th field="id" width="85%" hidden="true">instKey</th>
                                    <th field="name" width="90%">instData</th>
                                    <th field=" " formatter="commentImg" width="10%"></th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                        </table>
```

**2.dialog.js**

```
    function commentImg(){
    var dialog = new dijit.TooltipDialog({
        content:
            '<label for="name">Name:</label> <input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" id="name" name="name"><br>' +
            '<label for="hobby">Hobby:</label> <input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" id="hobby" name="hobby"><br>' +
            '<button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" type="submit">Save</button>'
    });

    var button = new dijit.form.DropDownButton({
        label: "",
        dropDown: dialog,
     //   iconClass: commentButtonIcon
    });
  return button;
}
```

Comment: No answer!!!put this line more clearly "I want when click on button it shows and on cancel button hide."

Comment: you want to run the same example right? tell me clearly what you want? your code its not display any dialog.

Answer (score 0):

1. try setting `closable : false` on tooltipDialog
2. use a dialog. tooltip dialog closes on mouseleave